# Can i submit to the app store with armv6 code only (not armv7) for an app supporting iOS 4.2+?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is armv7 an absolute requirement for submission to the app store currently?

The application is being built against the latest xcode, against the latest sdk (5.1) but with the minimum iOS version being 4.2. If we remove armv7 (due to a third party library, please dont ask) can we still submit to the app store with armv6 only?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes

I assume that if you are targeting iOS 4.2+ it includes 2nd gen devices (my iPod touch has 4.2.1 ) ...and those only work with armv6.

In any case...apps that work on armv6 work on armv7.

Now...if you haven't tested your app on 2nd gen device I suggest that you make minimum iOS required to be 4.3 (as in 3rd gen+)

Comment: rats you beat me to this answer, but I would like to add armv7 has been the instruction set for 3 or 4 years now.  Why hasnt the third party updated?  I wouldnt trust such a stale library unless they indicated they hand coded large portions of assembly instructions.

Comment: Like i said... 'please don't ask' :)